# Python Returning multiple values into another function

Tags: python

I am making an email complier of sorts and I am trying to return multiple values from my functions and input them into another function but when I run the code it keeps saying missing 1 required argument no matter how I try to do it. any suggestions ?

```
from email.message import EmailMessage
import getpass
import smtplib
import mimetypes
import os.path


def setup_users():
    user = input("Please enter your email ")
    print(f" this will be the senders email {user}")
    recipient = input("Please input senders ")
    print(f"this will be the recipients email {recipient}")
    return (user, recipient)


def load_smtp(sender, message):
    # sender = "sender@ example.com"
    print("connecting to smtp server will")
    mail_server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    mail_pass = getpass.getpass('Password? ')
    print(mail_pass)
    mail_server.login(sender, mail_pass)
    print("login sucessful")
    mail_server.send_message(message)
    print("email sent")
    mail_server.quit()

def create_email(user, recipient):
    sender = user
    recipient = recipient
    # setting to and from portion
    message = EmailMessage()
    message["From"] = sender
    message["to"] = recipient
    # setting up subject field
    message["Subject"] = f"Greetings this is from {sender} to {recipient}"
    body = """ Hey this is my first pythonic email program lets see how this works
    out! """
    # setting variable and putting body into a function
    message.set_content(body)
    return sender, message


if __name__ == "__main__":
    user = setup_users()
    email = create_email(user)
    print("gathering email data to complie")
    print("Starting program, will initiate load_smtp")
    smtp_server = load_smtp(email, user)
    print("sending email")
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and showing us the full traceback of the error?

Comment: thanks for your time but the other two answers got me working next time I ever post I will make sure I add the traceback error! thanks again!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write

```
return (user, recipient)
```

you are actually not returning 2 values. You are returning 1 value, and that 1 value is a tuple with 2 elements.

To get the two values out of the tuple, you have various options. One option is to use unpacking:

```
user, recipient = setup_users()
email = create_email(user, recipient)
```

Comment: thanks! I am new to programming I feel stupid after reading both answers lol

Answer (score 0):

While calling `create_email()`, You need to add `recipient`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    user = setup_users()
    email = create_email(user,recipient)
    print("gathering email data to complie")
    print("Starting program, will initiate load_smtp")
    smtp_server = load_smtp(email, user)
    print("sending email")
```